# MySql Update field or Insert if not exists, no primary key

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a 3 column (all Numeric) table with fields CustID (not unique), ProdID (not unique) and Price. The only 'uniqueness' is that no CustID/ProdID pair is duplicated. So, every client has a different 'Price' for every product. I am using the three line method. (a) search to see if pair exists, (b) if yes I update price, (c) if no I insert the new pair with the price. I haven't created indexes for the id's yet (it runs ok for dev purposes.)

Can anyone suggest a way of using the REPLACE instruction, most INSERT/ON DUPE examples seem to imply a primary key is necessary. I normally always do have a pk, just seemed wasteful for this requirement. Many thanks to anyone with time to help me.
Ken Ashton

Sorry, Michael, you had already given me the example. I'll figure out votes now, many thanks guys

Comment: You really should create a unique index across `CustID/ProdID`, not for performance purposes, to maintain integrity.

Comment: `CREATE INDEX idx_unique_custprod ON tblname (CustID, ProdID)`

Comment: Or better yet, create them as a PK: `ALTER TABLE tblname ADD PRIMARY KEY (CustID, ProdID)`

Comment: A primary key is never wasted. Small coding error on your part and CustId/ProdID gets duplicated, all sorts of weird and wonderfuls happen. Stop messing about and add one.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by Michael and Tony, a PK is never wasted. So it is always a good idea to have a PK in every table. So I'd first suggest that you create a PK and then use INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY.

For achieving what you want without the PK, you can first do a DELETE and then an INSERT. In fact that is what a REPLACE does internally.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm a beginner, I did appreciate the need for referential integrity, just thought this was too simple to screw up, but you have reinforced the importance for me. Could you give me an example of combining the two non.unique id fields into one unique field, I have never done that before, and perhaps show how that is used in the INSERT ON DUPLICATE command. Many thanks

Comment: for creating a common unique field, this should work - `ALTER TABLE tableName ADD UNIQUE INDEX idxName (CustID, ProdID);`